# Google Website Optimizer: track AJAX

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I am tracking AJAX goals in Google Analytics with no problems.
But I would like to use Google Website Optimizer to see what buttons or headlines get the most leads in our newsletter subscription form.

Since a new subscription only triggers AJAX/Javascript, I cannot add a separate success/thankyou.html page to track in Google Website Analyzer.

There is not much to find in Google's documentation about this.
Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Google Website Optimizer can be used with goal conversions as links or buttons.  The technique to use is to wrap the conversion code in a Javascript function and then to call this function from any link onclick or onsubmit event.

http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93181

Comment: I spent an hour searching for that page in google's help site. Thanks!

Comment: Link is gone. Now it redirects to help page :-(